# webpack & using node modules in an isomorphic package

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, jsdom

I am building an isomorphic package where I am using a flag in various files to detect if we are in the browser or in node.  If in node, I require an internal package ie `if (isNode) { require("/.nodeStuff) }` that has as one of its dependencies the `fs` module.  However, webpack does not like this for obvious reasons.  Is there any type of module-based webpack config file that I can configure to ignore the node-based requires entirely so that this does not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First option

As stated in the docs, in order to solve this isomorphic problem you could simply run two builds, one for each environment (node and web). The guide can be found [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/#multiple-targets). Keep in mind you should probably mock any built ins in the `clientConfig` by adding this block 
`node: { fs: 'empty',//any other node lib used }`. That way webpack will not complain and since your client code will be under the `!IS_NODE` condition the empty `fs` will never be used.

Although this is a solid solution you end up with 2 bundles and you need of course a way to distribute them to the correct platform each time.

#### Second way

This solution is based on the not very well known `__non_webpack_require__` function. This is a webpack specific function that will instruct the parser to avoid bundling this module that is being requested and assume that a global `require` function is available. This is exactly what happens while running in node instead of a browser.

//webpack.config.js

```
{
    mode: "development",
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    node: false
}
```

```js
// nodeStuff.js

const fs = __non_webpack_require__('fs'); //this will be transformed to require('fs')

fs.writeFileSync('some','thing)
```

That way since `nodeStuff.js` will only be required under the `IS_NODE` condition, the native `require` will be available.

I would suggest to use `__non_webpack_require__` on native libraries only, that you are sure that will be available!

Comment: Is there a way to do this so a dependent module can `npm install` or `npm link` the isomorphic module, where the dependent module is also isomorphic? I've explained it further in this [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092200/how-to-create-a-module-for-web-require-by-node-and-require-by-web-app)