# How to create a module for: web, require by node *and* require by web app?

Tags: node.js, webpack

TLDR; What's the best way to create a module that can be bundled for web, required by a node app, *and* required by a node module that is being bundled for web?

I started by having two entry points, one for node (index.js) and one for web (index-web.js). This works fine for bundling for web because webpack uses index-web.js. It also works for require by a node app because it picks up index.js. So first two items 'check'.

But it doesn't work if I require my module from a node app that is being bundled for web, because it picks up index.js by default. Maybe there's a simple way to handle that?

So Q1: Is there a way for the dependent module to pick up the web entry point (index-web.js) or even the web bundle when it `npm install`s or `npm link`s my module?

I have tried switching to just using index.js and putting conditional requires in there (conditional on `(typeof window === 'undefined')`) which kind of works, but:

A) I'm left with those annoying "Warning: Critical dependency" messages that I am about to look into (webpack [issue #196](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196)).

B) I have to modify the webpack.config.js of the *dependency* module to exclude certain builtins (using `externals`) that are now referenced because I'm using conditional requires in index.js. This is a deal breaker in the long run.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the meaning of this, *required by a node app that is being bundled for web*. It's either Node or web (browser).

Comment: Sorry, I mean required by a node module that is being bundled for web.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution is to use a combination of the npm node-detect package and the webpack DefinePlugin. This ensures that webpack only packages modules required for web and eliminates the webpack warnings about "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression".

So in your isomorphic modules (dependent *and* dependency):

```
npm install --save detect-node
```

or

```
yarn add detect-node
```

In both webpack.config.js:

```
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    // ...
    module.exports = {
      // ...
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          IS_BROWSER: true
        })
      ]
    }
```

In your code:

```
    const isNode = require(detect-node)
    if (isNode) {
        if (!IS_BROWSER) {
          // Ignored by webpack, handled by node
          safeJs.safeApi = require('./bootstrap')   
        }
    } else {
          // Ignored by node, handled by webpack
          window.safeJs = safeJs
          safeJs.safeApi = require('./bootstrap-web')
    }
```

Comment: How does this thing work? `if (!IS_BROWSER)` will equal to `if (!true)` so any js minifier will remove this code entirely.

Comment: That's correct, and if it is being used by node rather than minified for a browser, the code with remain. That's the idea. I've since realised it isn't really a full solution though, because you may not be able (or want to) set IS_BROWSER in a dependent module / app. I found a solution for my use case by setting an alternative entry point in package.json (ie for 'browser', alongside the normal entry point, 'main'). But that won't cover all cases, and I don't think there is a general solution at this time.